# Formatting a text file and exporting a text file

Tags: vba, excel, text

I have a Range of data in text file like 102201906000-102201911999-23451 around thousands. i want to create a new text file to create the range into numbers like.

```
102201906000 23451
102201906001 23451
102201906002 23451
```

till

```
102201911999 23451
```

Keeping the last digit as fixed.
I have made following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim rngEnd As String
    Dim rng1 As String
    Dim rng2 As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim Num As Range
    For Each Num In Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
        lCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        rngEnd = Split(Num, "-")(2)
        rng1 = Split(Num, "-")(0) - 1
        rng2 = Split(Num, "-")(1)
        For x = 1 To rng2 - rng1
            Cells(x, lCol + 1) = rng1 + x & " " & rngEnd
        Next x
    Next Num
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But as i have huge data i am unable to use it properly.

Can i get some help on to create a text file itself when i run a macro without using the spreadsheet.

Waiting for expert advises.

Comment: What does your question have to do with text files? You mention them in the question and even suggest that you would rather deal with text files directly, but your code has nothing about reading from and writing to text files.

Comment: @John Coleman Thanks for replying .. !! I have data in text file.. but i am unable to make changes in text file .. so i am importing them into excel and using above code.. as i have huge data volume.. above code is not helping me out.. Please advise,,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a text file and want to create another textfile where each line like `102201906000-102201911999-23451` is replaced by a number of lines like  `102201906000 23451` it is more natural to use VBScript than straight VBA. You can bypass the need to pull the data into Excel (but -- it is written as an Excel macro so you need to call it from Excel. With minor modification you can remove Excel from the loop completely and use pure VBScript).

To use it you have to include a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your projects (`Tools/References` in the VBA editor).

```
Sub ExpandData(inName As String, outName As String)
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim tsIn As TextStream
    Dim tsOut As TextStream
    Dim startNum, endNum, i, line 'variants

    On Error GoTo err_handler

    Set tsIn = FSO.OpenTextFile(inName, ForReading)
    Set tsOut = FSO.OpenTextFile(outName, ForWriting, True)

    Do While tsIn.AtEndOfStream = False
        line = Split(tsIn.ReadLine, "-")
        If UBound(line) = 2 Then
            startNum = CDec(line(0))
            endNum = CDec(line(1))
            For i = startNum To endNum
                tsOut.WriteLine i & " " & line(2)
            Next i
        End If
    Loop
    tsIn.Close
    tsOut.Close
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    Debug.Print "I'm confused!"
End Sub
```

Used like thus (inName must be different from outName):

```
Sub test()
    ExpandData "C:\Programs\test.txt", "C:\Programs\testout.txt"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to write then all at once. Looping through and examining them individually should not be necessary if they are sequential.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lr As Long, nmbr As Long, bgn As String, nd As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<~~set this worksheet properly!
        lr = .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        nd = .Cells(1, 1).Value2
        bgn = left(nd, 7)
        nmbr = CLng(Mid(nd, 8, 5))
        nd = right(nd, 5)
        With .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(lr, 1)
            .Formula = "=""" & bgn & """&TEXT(ROW(" & Rows(nmbr).Address(0, 0) & "), ""00000_)"")&""" & nd & """"
            .Value = .Value2
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This generate sequential number based upon the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D). The prefix and suffix are peeled off the first value in A1 only once and used afterwards as string vars.

[image: Sequenced numbers]

Comment: Dear Thanks for your help. But i want a series of nembers into a sequence.102201906000-102201911999-23451
should be written as 102210906000 23451, and 102201906001 23451,102201906002 23451 and so on till 102201911999 23451

Comment: You mean exactly like the ones in the image I generated using that code?

Comment: Yes...This is a range of numbers i.e. 1 to 10. above code does this. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. Keeping the last digit stable i.e. 23451.  I have these numbers in thousands. so excel is unable to do that with mine code.